# changing password using pexpect and passwd non-interactivly?

Tags: python

I am trying to learn python to change users password non-interactively but nothing seems to be working.
`pexepect` module of python seems promising, so I am just trying to use it.
This [tutorial](http://linux.byexamples.com/archives/346/python-how-to-access-ssh-with-pexpect/) is nice but it does not work.
There's lots of code on Internet regarding this but none of them seems to work.
And nor does my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import pexpect
import time
def ChangePassword(user, pass):
    passwd = pexpect.spawn("/usr/bin/passwd %s" % user)

    for x in xrange(2):
        # wait for password: to come out of passwd's stdout
        passwd.expect("password: ")
        # send pass to passwd's stdin
        passwd.sendline(pass)
        time.sleep(0.1)

ChangePassword('rajesh', 'bar') # changes user "foo"'s password to "bar"
```

Error:

```
bash-3.00# ./solpas7.py
  File "./solpas7.py", line 4
    def ChangePassword(user, pass):
                                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

EDIT : i changed pass to pa but not i am getting a lot and the password does not changes.

```
bash-3.00# ./solpas7.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./solpas7.py", line 14, in ?
    ChangePassword('rajesh', 'bar') # changes user "foo"'s password to "bar"
  File "./solpas7.py", line 9, in ChangePassword
    passwd.expect("password: ")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/pexpect.py", line 1311, in expect
    return self.expect_list(compiled_pattern_list, timeout, searchwindowsize)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/pexpect.py", line 1325, in expect_list
    return self.expect_loop(searcher_re(pattern_list), timeout, searchwindowsize                                              )
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/pexpect.py", line 1409, in expect_loop
    raise TIMEOUT (str(e) + '\n' + str(self))
pexpect.TIMEOUT: Timeout exceeded in read_nonblocking().
<pexpect.spawn object at 0x80e306c>
version: 2.3 ($Revision: 399 $)
command: /usr/bin/passwd
args: ['/usr/bin/passwd', 'rajesh']
searcher: searcher_re:
    0: re.compile("password: ")
buffer (last 100 chars): New Password:
before (last 100 chars): New Password:
after: pexpect.TIMEOUT
match: None
match_index: None
exitstatus: None
flag_eof: False
pid: 4683
child_fd: 3
closed: False
timeout: 30
delimiter: pexpect.EOF
logfile: None
logfile_read: None
logfile_send: None
maxread: 2000
ignorecase: False
searchwindowsize: None
delaybeforesend: 0.05
delayafterclose: 0.1
delayafterterminate: 0.1
```

Comment: `pass` is a reserved keyword ;) Using something else will at least remove the syntax error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use [`pass`](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#pass) as a variable name. It's a reserved keyword.

Edit:
pexpect is waiting for the string `"password: "` but as you can tell from the error message `passwd` outputs `"New Password: "` (note the capital p) on your system.

```
buffer (last 100 chars): New Password:
before (last 100 chars): New Password:
```

Instead of `passwd.expect("password: ")` you need to use `passwd.expect("Password: ")`.

Comment: this is what i did just now `bash-3.00# passwd rajesh
New Password:
Re-enter new Password:
passwd: password successfully changed for rajesh`

Comment: is it looking for the string `New Password:` and Re-enter new Password:`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this to make your search case insensitive:

```
passwd.expect('(?i)password:')
```